# How do I identify PrimeFaces tooltip backgrouond color?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces6.1 and my primefaces.THEME is afternoon.  I would like to make my panel overlay look the same as the tooltips.  Therefore, I need to figure out what the tooltip background color is.  It's obvious the font color is white.

I have found information on how to override the tooltip colors and I guess I could do that, but I really like the theme color.  Anyone have an idea on this?

Comment: A browser developer tool?

Comment: Rence below pointed me to exactly what I need.  However, you make a good point.  I tried to use inspect element but couldn't get the tooltip before it went away.  I changed some of the settings and was able to use inspect element and whalha!  That works too.  Thanks Kukeltje!

Answer (score 2):

You could find out the back-ground color for `p:tooltip` used in Primefaces 6.1 in `components.css`

Path: `primefaces-6.1.jar\META-INF\resources\primefaces`

open the `components.css` 
and search `ui-tooltip-text{padding:3px 10px;background-color:#4c4c4c;color:#fff}`

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'm looking for.  Much appreciated!

Comment: I would love to.  However I only have 11 reputation and cannot vote the up arrow until I get 15 reputation.  Correction, I can and did vote and it's supposed to be recorded but does not show.